# Conversion of .iqy file to .xlsx file using python/vba

Tags: python, vba

I have downloaded some data from Sharepoint in *.iqy format (this is the only format in which the data can be downloaded). Post this, I perform the following steps to open and save the *.iqy file in *.xlsx format.

- Open the *.iqy file.
- A dialog box appears (Microsoft Excel Security Notice) where I click "ENABLE".
- Now another dialog box appears (Import Data) in which I click "OK" without changing any options.
- The data now appears in a spreadsheet which I then save as a *.xlsx file.

Is there any way to perform the above steps via a script (either in VBA or Python)?

P.S: Unfortunately I'm not authorized to share a sample file of some sort since the data is controlled.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.